# How to set classes on all Material UI Dialogs universally?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have many [Material UI dialog](https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/) I want to set `rg-dialog` class on all of them. What should I do?

```
<Dialog
    classes={{ root: 'rg-dialog' }}
    open={workflowHistoryDialogVisible}
>
    <DialogTitle>History</DialogTitle>
    <DialogContent>
        [WorkflowHistory]
    </DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>
        <MatButton className="btn-warning text-white"
            onClick={() => setWorkflowHistoryDialogVisibleAction(false)}>Close</MatButton>
    </DialogActions>
</Dialog>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set styles globally for material components, try [overriding the default material theme](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#5-global-theme-variation). I might look like:

```
const themeOptions = {
  overrides: {
    MuiDialog: {
      // your override styles here. for example, the following overrides dialog's "root" class
      root: {
        padding: 5
      }
    }
  }
};

const theme = createMuiTheme(themeOptions);
```

Then use the modified theme in your `ThemeProvider`

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
```

If you are new to themes in material-ui, [check out the docs](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/)

Comment: By the way, typing is most helpful with material-ui Theming